# Email pattern not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, email, lightninginput, pattern

Hi this pattern is not working in an Aura component and i've no idea why...

```
<lightning:input aura:id="Eemail" 
                 name="email"
                 value="{!v.client.Email__c}"
                 messageWhenPatternMismatch="Por favor, introduzca un email válido"
                 messageWhenTypeMismatch="Por favor, introduzca un email válido"
                 label="Email" type="email"
                 required="{!not(empty(v.opportunityLineItem.VariableDescuentoCampana__c))}"
                 pattern="^[\w._%-]+@[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$"/>
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You generally should not attempt to validate email addresses with a regex. It is difficult to do so accurately. Your regex will fail to validate any email with a TLD longer than 3 characters, of which there are many, as well as any containing a non-Roman character.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed i'll take that in consideration, but still don'tunderstand why is this pattern not working. If a write "Test", it accepts "Test", when it should throw messageWhenTypeMismatch.